# clicking on the popup window option 'yes' is not working

Tags: selenium, webdriver, popup

I have the below popup window when I click on something. I need to select the 'Yes' option in there. I tried switch window and alerts as well , but nothing seems to work. I used the id=yes and css options as well. Any thoughts?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFQZs.png)

Comment: did you happen to check if the button is inside a frame? What is the exception being thrown? Also, it is a div element. Can you try expanding the span and see if there is any button element inside. If possible, please copy the expanded DOM structure here.

Comment: I think you have to click on `span` not `div` So use `xpath= .//div[@id='yes']/span` and is it possible for you to share your `url` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` above the pseudo class, does it have any content in it (it looks to be expandable)? If so, I would expand that and see if there are any css selectors you can leverage or XPath.

I think the reason that the`id=yes` doesn't work is because its a `<div>` rather than some other elements that can be clicked/interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

Use Robot class.Check if it helps.

```
     // create object to robot class
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        // press tab to navigate to Yes Button
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        // press tab second time if required
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        // press enter key
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```